# How to restore from backup file realm database in Android

Tags: android, realm-mobile-platform

I had try many ways for restore realm. I had try like as from this [sample code](https://medium.com/glucosio-project/example-class-to-export-import-a-realm-database-on-android-c429ade2b4ed#.8lwsves79). But restore realm db from backup file is not working. how can do other ways?

Comment: define "not working"

Answer (score 0):

`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` no longer works as of Android 10, unless you use a special flag in AndroidManifest. And it won't work at all in Android 11.

You need to refactor your backup/restore procedure to work with [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage) and the Storage Access Framework. This tutorial I made is for SQLite, but it should be basically the same with a Realm database:

https://medium.com/@gavingt/refactoring-my-backup-and-restore-feature-to-comply-with-scoped-storage-e2b6c792c3b

You'll also likely want to disable write-ahead logging in `onOpen()`. This is what it looks like in SQLite:

```
    @Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    //disable write-ahead logging to make backup/restore work on all devices.
    db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
}
```